# Is there a plugin for (neo)vim that allows to jump to a possition by label, similar to things like vimium do?

Tags: cursor-movement, navigation

With some browser plugins like [vimium](https://vimium.github.io/), one can press a key and all links on the open webpage get labeled with a short combination of letters. If you then type that combination, the corresponding link is clicked.

**Is there a plugin for (neo)vim that can do that?**

E.g, if you typed a normal mode command, the visible text would get labeled, and then you could press something like <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>t</kbd> to get to the "any instance" part of the document below. Here is a mock-up of what that might look like:

[image: labels for text positions]

Where the file open in vim would look like this:

[image: same file without labels]

Comment: https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion

Comment: There are a number of plugins that do something similar, I believe. Easymotion is the first one that comes to mind for me, too. Also, please tell me you generated that mockup in some scripted way and not by hand. ;)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't find it for the life of me. One of you should write this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of most known plugins that does it -- [vim-easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion)

You might also check [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) for a similar but a bit different approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[leap.nvim](https://github.com/ggandor/leap.nvim) is the best one, very powerful to customize :)

also 100% lua